# Trying to find the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20

Tags: java, algorithm, math, division, greatest-common-divisor

I'm trying to find the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20. We are given that 2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers from 1 to 10 without any remainder. My find() finds the number starting from 2520 that is divisible by all numbers from 1-20 but is returning 2520 for some reason. I cannot find what's wrong about my find()?

```
  public class Solution  {

  public ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();


// creating a list of integers from 1 to 20
public ArrayList<Integer> addtolist() {
  for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    list.add(i);
  }
  return list;
}

// finds the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all 
of the numbers from 1 to 20

public int find() {
  int num = 2520;
  while(true) {
    for(int i: list) {
      if(num % i == 0) {
        return num;
      }
      else {
        num = num + 1;
      }

    }
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Solution sol = new Solution();
  sol.addtolist();
  System.out.println(sol.find());//2520
}


}
```

Comment: Find primes less than or equal to 20, and then find the highest power of each that's less than or equal to 20. Multiply them together. That's `16*9*5*7*11*13*17*19=232792560`

Comment: this is called least common multiple **LCM** just in case you want to know what to google, efficient solution is done by Sieve of Eratosthenes **SoE**

Answer (score 1):

Your `find` function returns `num` if *any* `i` in `list` divides it. It should only return `num` if *every* `i` in `num` is a divisor.

Although it has to be said that this is far from the most efficient solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You return from the for loop when `(num % i == 0)`, given that i starts at 1 this always true.  Instead you need to wait until the end to return:

```
public int find() {
  int num = 2520;
  while(true) {
    boolean allDivisible = true;
    for(int i: list) {
      if(num % i != 0) {
        allDivisible = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (allDivisible) {
      return num;
    else {
      num = num + 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
for(int i: list) {
  if(num % i == 0) {
    return num; // Returns immediately. 
  }
  else {
    num = num + 1;
  }
}
```

you return as soon as you find some number in the list that has a match. What you want to do is only return when you have found a value that matches all in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Nice question!

```
long answer = LongStream.iterate(1, n -> n + 1)
    .filter(n -> IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 20).allMatch(f -> n % f == 0))
    .findFirst().getAsLong();
```

Answer is 232792560

There are obviously plenty of shortcuts using math (e.g. only looking at even numbers, ignoring numbers in 1 to 20 that are factors of other numbers in that range).